# Putting a texture on one surface of a cube isn't working

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d

I'm trying to put a texture on one surface of a cube (if facing the XY plane the texture would be facing you).

No texture is getting drawn, only the wireframe and I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong. I think it's the vertex coordinates?

Here's some code:

```
struct paperVertex {
    D3DXVECTOR3 pos;
    DWORD color;        // The vertex color
    D3DXVECTOR2 texCoor;
    paperVertex(D3DXVECTOR3 p, DWORD c, D3DXVECTOR2 t) {pos = p; color = c; texCoor = t;}
    paperVertex() {pos = D3DXVECTOR3(0,0,0); color = 0; texCoor = D3DXVECTOR2(0,0);}
};
```

---

```
D3DCOLOR color1 = D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 255);
D3DCOLOR color2 = D3DCOLOR_XRGB(200, 200, 200);
vertices[0] = paperVertex(D3DXVECTOR3(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), color1, D3DXVECTOR2(1,0));  // bottom left corner of tex
vertices[1] = paperVertex(D3DXVECTOR3(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f), color1, D3DXVECTOR2(0,0));  // top left corner of tex
vertices[2] = paperVertex(D3DXVECTOR3( 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f), color1, D3DXVECTOR2(0,1));  // top right corner of tex
vertices[3] = paperVertex(D3DXVECTOR3(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), color1, D3DXVECTOR2(1,1));   // bottom right corner of tex
vertices[4] = paperVertex(D3DXVECTOR3(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f), color1, D3DXVECTOR2(0,0));
vertices[5] = paperVertex(D3DXVECTOR3(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f), color2, D3DXVECTOR2(0,0));
vertices[6] = paperVertex(D3DXVECTOR3(1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f), color2, D3DXVECTOR2(0,0));
vertices[7] = paperVertex(D3DXVECTOR3(1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f), color1, D3DXVECTOR2(0,0));
```

---

```
D3DXCreateTextureFromFile( md3dDev, "texture.bmp", &gTexture);
md3dDev->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MINFILTER, D3DTEXF_LINEAR);
md3dDev->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MAGFILTER, D3DTEXF_LINEAR);
```

---

```
md3dDev->SetTexture(0, gTexture);
md3dDev->SetStreamSource(0, mVtxBuf, 0, sizeof(paperVertex));
md3dDev->SetVertexDeclaration(paperDecl);
md3dDev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_FILLMODE, D3DFILL_WIREFRAME);
md3dDev->SetIndices(mIndBuf);
md3dDev->DrawIndexedPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, 0, 0, VTX_NUM, 0, NUM_TRIANGLES);
```

Comment: `->SetRenderState(D3DRS_FILLMODE, D3DFILL_WIREFRAME);` this will ONLY render wireframe. No solid render, no proper texture. So use solid fill or just don't change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**disclaimer:** I have no Direct3D experience, but solid OpenGL and general computer graphics experience. And since the underlying concepts don't really differ, I attempt an answer, of whose correctness I'm 99% sure.

You call `md3dDev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_FILLMODE, D3DFILL_WIREFRAME)` immediately before rendering and wonder why only the wireframe is drawn?

Keep in mind that using a texture doesn't magically turn a wireframe model into a solid model. It is still a wireframe model with the texture only applied to the wireframe. You can only draw the whole primitve as wireframe or not.

Likewise does using texture coordinates of (0,0) not magically disable texturing for individual faces. You can only draw the whole primitive textured or not, though you might play with the texture coordinates and the texture's wrapping mode (and maybe the texture border) to make the "non-textured" faces use a uniform color from the texture and thus *look* like not textured.

But in general to achieve such deviating render styles (like textured/non-textured, but especially wireframe/solid) in a single primitive, you won't get around splitting the primitive into multiple ones and drawing each one with its dedicated render style.

**EDIT:** According to your comment: If you don't need wireframe, why enable it then? Besides disabling wireframe, with your current texture coordinates the other faces won't just have a single color from the texture but some strange distorted version of the texture. This is because your vertices (and their texture coordinates) are shared between different faces, but the texture coordinates at the moment are created only for the front face to look reasonable.

In such a situation, you won't get around duplicating vertices, so that each face uses a set of 4 unique vertices. In the case of a cube you won't actually need an index array anymore, because each face needs its own vertices. This is due to the fact, that a vertex conceptually represents all of the vertex' attributes (position, color, texCoord, ...) and you cannot have a two vertices sharing a position but having different texture coordinates (you can but you need two distinct vertices). Once you've duplicated the vertices accordingly, you can give each of the corner vertices their respective texture coordinates (which would be the usual [0,1]-quad if you want them textured normally, or all 0s if you want them to have a single color, in this case the color of the bottom left (or top left in D3D?) corner of the texture).

The same problem arises if you want to light the cube and need normals per-face, istead of interpolated per-vertex normals. In this case you also have to introduce duplicate vertices only deviating in their normal attribute. Always keep in mind that a vertex conceptually consists of all the vertex attributes and if two vertices have the same position but a different color/normal/texCoord/... they are conceptually (and practically) different vertices.

Comment: I have no need for wireframe. Is that the only thing I need to change?

Comment: The other surfaces are kind of irrelevant I don't mind if they are a single color or even are the same texture

Comment: @robev Updated my answer. If it really doesn't matter how they look, it should work this way, but don't expect them to look reasonable (single color or proper texture).

Comment: Sorry what if l want the front and back surface to have the same texture but thetop bottom and sides are irrelevant

Comment: @robev This would also work. Just change the other 4 vertices to take reasonable values (as seen when looking onto the back-face).